# What is the meaning of 横分け眼鏡?

Tags: meaning, words, expressions, idioms, offensive-words

A girl is offending a boy that wears glasses by saying:

> 気持ち悪いんだよ、横分け眼鏡。

I guess 横分け眼鏡 is a kind of offensive thing referring to his glasses or his eyesight, maybe similar to the English `four-eyes`, but what is its exact meaning? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

横分け is a word that refers to "side-parted hair style", not the type of the glasses he wears. 横分け of men's hair is better known as 七三分け【しちさんわけ】 (literally "7:3 parted").

The combination of 横分け and 眼鏡 is a stereotype of typical middle-aged Japanese businessmen like this:

[image]

横分け is usually not used as a derogatory term, but some Japanese people find 横分け as being mediocre or a bit old-fashioned. (And there are also people [who find 横分け眼鏡 cool](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2138062849037829801)).

Anyway, she seems to dislike 横分け眼鏡. Maybe she thinks it looks too old for his age.